# How do I comment out ERB  in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I understand that commenting in rails is done with '#' but if I try to comment out ERB tags, I always run into problems

```
 <%= link_to "Make default", make_default_admin_state_path(state) %>
```

Where would you put the '#' on this code?

I tried to put it outside the <% and it did nothing. when I put it inside, there was an error message

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
<%#= link_to "Make default", make_default_admin_state_path(state) %>
```

`<%# %>` is an ERB comment: the dangling `=` makes no difference, and can be left in.

Answer (score 17):

Just now I wanted to just leave a block out of the template because it was currently useless, if that's the case I suggest:

```
<% if false %>
  this block of code won't give runtime errors..
  <%= alm lkjsxajklla 10293 aslkj no problems! %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is what I use to comment out ERB. I usually add something to make the commented block stand out because this screws up the text highlighting. I like the `if false` approach because it doesn't get screwed up when there is `<% %>` inside. I usually un-indent `if false` and `end` completely and add something after. Something like: `<% if false #-----\/----\/----\/---- %> \n..\n.. <%=  ..... %>\n <% end #____/\____/\____/\____%>`. This makes the comment area obvious.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- %= link_to "Make default", make_default_admin_state_path(state) % -->
```

Comment: That'll still show up in the HTML, which may or may not be an issue. (Heck, it might even be desired.)

Comment: Yeah but had already answered with the erb comment, decided to put the html one ;-)

Answer (score -1):

you can do it like one the @Dominic Goet did.If you stuck from it you can try this one

```
<%=# link_to "Make default", make_default_admin_state_path(state) % >
```

or

```
< %#= link_to "Make default", make_default_admin_state_path(state) %>
```